# Encryption and Decryption in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, encryption, password-encryption

I have to encrypt and then join 2 tables. Common column for both table is 'NAME'.
When I encrypt 'Name',salary, in both tables consecutively, i should get same value for 'name' so that i can join both tables based on that encrypted 'name' value.

Thanks in advance !!!

**Table : 1**

```
Name|    Date     |  Salary
A   |  01/01/2019 |  100
A   |  01/02/2019 |  200
B   |  01/01/2019 |  300
```

**Table : 2**

```
Name| Date of Birth |  No of Absence
A   |  10/12/1991   |  10
B   |  10/12/1992   |  20
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to preform encryption. One of the way is that you can hash the data in columns `NAME` and `Salary` with a secret key.

There are a lot of hashing algorithms, including but not limited to `md5`, `sha1`, `sha256`. The [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/pgcrypto.html) module in Postgresql provides some hashing functions for you to use.

No matter which hashing algorithm you use, same value is always being hashed to a same string. For example md5 hash of `A` is always `7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29`, and that of `B` is always `9d5ed678fe57bcca610140957afab571`. So you can join tables as usual.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  "Name" VARCHAR(1),
  "Date" TIMESTAMP,
  "Salary" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table1
  ("Name", "Date", "Salary")
VALUES
  (pgp_sym_encrypt('A', 'key'), '01/01/2019', '100'),
  (pgp_sym_encrypt('A', 'key'), '01/02/2019', '200'),
  (pgp_sym_encrypt('B', 'key'), '01/01/2019', '300');


CREATE TABLE table2 (
  "Name" VARCHAR(1),
  "Date of Birth" TIMESTAMP,
  "No of Absence" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table2
  ("Name", "Date of Birth", "No of Absence")
VALUES
  (pgp_sym_encrypt('A', 'key'), '10/12/1991', '10'),
  (pgp_sym_encrypt('B', 'key'), '10/12/1992', '20');

SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(table1."Name", 'key'), table1."Salary", table1."Date", pgp_sym_decrypt(table2."Name", 'key'), table2."Date of Birth", table2."No of Absence" 
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1."Name" = table2."Name");
```

Note that pgcrypto is installed.

Comment: `hash the data in columns NAME and Salary with a secret key.` You mean like HMAC?

Comment: *"There are many ways to preform encryption. One of the way is that you can hash..."* - encryption and hashing are two very different things.